# Index out of bound unexpectedly

Tags: java

I was trying to make a program which would read a string and put complete words into an array of string. This has been done by avoiding space. Here is my code:

```
String s ="Hello how are you";
String str = "";
int i=0;

String strArr[] = new String[100];
int j=0;


    while(j<=s.length()-1)              
    {       
        if(s.charAt(j)!=' ')
        {
            while(s.charAt(j)!=' ')
            {
                str = str+s.charAt(j);
                j++;
            }           
        }

        j++;
        if(!str.equals(null))
        {
            strArr[i++] = str;
            str=null;
        }
    }
```

The array of strings should contain `Hello`,`how`,`are`,`you`. But 
it is showing `String index out of range: 17` but I can't find why it is behaving like this?

Comment: I disagree with the down-votes here. This is a perfectly reasonable attempt at the task at hand. It is *so* reasonable that only two lines need be changed to get the correct outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This code is all manner of bugged up.. if you just want an array of the words separated by spaces then you can use this:

```
String s = "Hello how are you";
String[] words = s.split(" +");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", words));
```

If you really don't want to use `split`, then this will do the same thing. It may have a nested loop but it's still linear time since they're incrementing the same counter:

```
String s = "Hello how are you";

List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // increment until you find the start of a word, a non-space
    if (s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        int wordStart = i;
        // increment to the end of the word, a non-space or end of string
        while ((i < s.length()) && (s.charAt(i) != ' ')) { i++; }
        // add the word to your list
        words.add(s.substring(wordStart, i));
    }
}

System.out.println(words);

// if you really need it as an array
String[] wordsArray = words.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I make some adaptations in your initial code and I believe that here is a simpliest solution:

```
String s ="Hello how are you";
String str = "";
int i = 0;

String strArr[] = new String[100];
int j = 0;

while(j < s.length()) {
    if(s.charAt(j) == ' ') {
        if (!str.isEmpty()) {
            strArr[i++] = str;
        }
        str = "";
    } else {
        str += s.charAt(j);
    }

    j++;
}
if (!str.isEmpty()) {
    strArr[i++] = str;
}
```

Here it is necessary only one loop to split the string.

Answer (score 0):

I this loop:

```
while(s.charAt(j)!=' ')
{
    str = str+s.charAt(j);
    j++;
}
```

you're incrementing `j` without any control. You should add a check to `while` loop: `while(j < s.length() && s.charAt(j) != ' ')`.

P.S.: You have 2 `if`s and `while`s with same conditions, I'd refactor.

P.S.2: `str.equals(null)` will always be `false` if `str` is not `null`.

P.S.3: you can use `String#split` for this - much more error prone.

Comment: I had tried this solution still it was showing the same error.

Comment: With the check first? Before `s.charAt(j) != ' '`?

Comment: its pointing to the while loop present inside the if condition

`while(s.charAt(j)!=' ' && j < s.length())`

Comment: So you did not check my solution... Already asked if with the check BEFORE `s.charAt(j) != ' '`...

Comment: I have applied the checks on both if condition and while loop respectively

Comment: I don't even know, how to explain that. This goes first: `j < s.length()`, then this: `s.charAt(j)!=' '`... That cannot be simpler. I've explained it 3 times, if you still don't get it, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I will start this by saying I'm not an expert, but I believe I know what is going wrong here.

```
while(j<=s.length()-1)              
{       
    if(s.charAt(j)!=' ')
    {
        while(s.charAt(j)!=' ') //Will constantly be true as long as the previous if statement is true
        {
            str = str+s.charAt(j);
            j++; //
        }           
    }

    j++;
    if(!str.equals(null))
    {
        strArr[i++] = str;
        str=null;
    }
}
```

Essentially you're continuously increasing j on your second while loop.
I suggest using a for loop instead:

```
for(j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
    if(s.charAt(j)!=' ') {
            str = str+s.charAt(j);
        }
    if(!str.equals(null) {
        strArr[i++] = str;
        str=null;
    }
}
```

If anyone sees an issue in this, please let me know and I will correct it.

Comment: First: his won't even compile, second `!str.equals(null)` is always `true`.

Comment: I'm also noticing now that he is involving char types into this. If he is intending on having the array have Strings, he shouldn't even be involving chars. I guess I need to know a bit more of what he wants before I can really help with much

Comment: Okay. Well if that is the case I recommend looking at xtratic's answer, as it is the most concise one here

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the condition in the inner `while` loop. You need to make sure you do not go out of bounds there.

Also, your `str=null;` line needs to be changed to `str="";`, otherwise you get the String `"null"` in your result.

**Your original solution, fixed with minor changes:**

```java
String s ="Hello how are you";
String str = "";
int i=0;

String strArr[] = new String[100];
int j=0;


while(j<=s.length()-1)
{
  if(s.charAt(j)!=' ')
  {
    while(j<=s.length()-1 && s.charAt(j)!=' ') // Added a check here
    {
      str = str+s.charAt(j);
      j++;
    }
  }

  j++;
  if(!str.equals(null))
  {
    strArr[i++] = str;
    str=""; // Changed this line
  }
}
```

*Note: I would rather not refactor your code for you, but I do agree with the other commenters; you could have handled this with a way more readable and bug-resistant algorithm. I will leave it to you to figure that out, since it isn't what you were asking for.*